# commerce drupal 7 cache module suggestion

Tags: 7, caching, performance, commerce

Any experiences of suggestion about what cache module to use in with a commerce store? I have been researching about it and I cannot find any suggestions or problems that you can face when using Drupal commerce with caching.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use Authcache module with memcache module

http://drupal.org/project/authcache

Also check Entity cache for Drupal Commerce module

http://drupal.org/node/1588814/release

Comment: have you tried with commerce? any suggestion?

Comment: not yet, but I tried it with authenticated pages with memcache module, the results were good, page load time after installing it decreased. Also check Entity cache for Drupal Commerce module - I haven't tried it yet